# Angular Calendar Logic Issue (+Plunker Help)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to get some help on the calendar logic so only one cell can be selected at a time from the table, but the Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/F0MIoZIQ3pkhuDgcH2wo?p=info doesn't seem to be working. Advice would be much appreciated - I've been stuck on this for way too long!

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('bookerApp', []);

app.controller('BookerController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

    $scope.months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    $scope.rows = [
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
        [29, 30, 31, '', '', '', ''],
        ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
        ];

    $scope.currDate = new Date();
    $scope.daysInMonth = 0;
    $scope.currDay = 0;
    $scope.monthStart = 0;
    $scope.monthEnd = 0;
    $scope.dayStart = 0;
    $scope.dif = 0;
    $scope.times = [];
    $scope.timeDate = new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    $scope.test;
    $scope.isChanged = [];
    $scope.lastChanged = '';
    $scope.isAnyActive = false;
    $scope.rowsArray = [''];

    $scope.idCount = 0;
    $scope.idNum = [[0,0],[0,0]];


    for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
        $scope.idNum[x] = [];
        for (y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++) {
            $scope.idNum[x][y] = $scope.idCount;
            $scope.isChanged[$scope.idCount] = false;
            $scope.idCount += 1;

        }
    }

    $scope.checkIs = function (id) {

            if ($scope.isChanged[id] == false && $scope.isAnyActive == false) {
                $scope.isChanged[id] = true;
                $scope.isAnyActive = true;
                $scope.lastChanged = id;
            }
            else if ($scope.isChanged[id] == true && $scope.isAnyActive == true){
                $scope.isChanged[id] = false;
                $scope.isAnyActive = false;
                $scope.lastChanged = '';
            }
            else if ($scope.isChanged[id] == false && $scope.isAnyActive == true) {
                $scope.isChanged[id] = true;
                $scope.isChanged[lastChanged] = false;
            }


    }

    $scope.calLayout = function(){

        for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
            for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                if ($scope.rows[x][y] == 1) {
                    $scope.dif = y - $scope.monthStart.getDay();

                }
            }
        }



        for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
            for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                $scope.rows[x][y] += $scope.dif;
            }
        }


        for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
            for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                if ($scope.rows[x][y] <= 0){
                    $scope.rows[x][y] = '';
                }
            }
        }

        for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
            for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                    if (($scope.rows[x][y] - $scope.dif) == $scope.daysInMonth){
                        for (i = -($scope.dif); i > 0; i--){
                            if (y+i > 6) {
                                $scope.rows[x+1][y-7+i] = ($scope.rows[x][y]+i);
                            }
                            else {
                                $scope.rows[x][y+i] = ($scope.rows[x][y]+i);
                            }
                        }
                    }


            }
        }
        $scope.idCount2 = 0;
        for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
            for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                $scope.rowsArray[$scope.idCount2] = $scope.rows[x][y];
                $scope.idCount2 += 1;
            }
        }
    }


    $scope.getDaysInMonth = function () {
        monthStart = new Date($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth(), 1);
        monthEnd = new Date ($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth()+1, 1);
        $scope.monthStart = monthStart;
        $scope.monthEnd = monthEnd;
        $scope.daysInMonth = (monthEnd - monthStart)/(1000*60*60*24);
        $scope.calLayout();
    }

    $scope.getMonthStartDay = function (){
        $scope.currDay = $scope.currDate.getDate();
        return $scope.monthStart.getDay();
    }

    $scope.setActive = function(num) {
        $scope.activated = num;
    }

    $scope.isActive = function(num) {
        /*Insert if statement to disallow empty cells from being selected*/; 
        return $scope.activated === num;
    }

    $scope.nextMonth = function (){
        $scope.resetRows();
        $scope.currDate = new Date ($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth()+1, $scope.currDate.getDate());
        $scope.getDaysInMonth();
        $scope.getTimeList();
    }

    $scope.lastMonth = function (){
        $scope.resetRows();
        $scope.currDate = new Date ($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth()-1, $scope.currDate.getDate());
        $scope.getDaysInMonth();
    }

    $scope.isThisMonth = function (){
        var now = new Date;
        if ($scope.currDate.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && $scope.currDate.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear()){
            return false;
        } 
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }



    $scope.rowIsNotEmpty = function () {

        for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++) {

            var rowCount = 0;

            for (y=0; y<$scope.rows.length; y++) {
                if ($scope.rows[x][y] == '') {
                    rowCount += 1;
                }
            }

            if (rowCount == rows[x].length){
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    $scope.resetRows = function (){

        $scope.rows = [
            [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
            [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
            [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
            [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
            [29, 30, 31, '', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
            ];

    }

    $scope.getTimeList = function() {


        for (i=0; i < 48; i++) {
            $scope.times[i] = ($scope.timeDate.getTime())/(60*1000);
            $scope.timeDate += (30* 60* 1000);

        }
    }


}]);
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='bookerApp'>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/styles.css'>
<script src='js/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/controllers/BookerController.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='BookerController' ng-init='getDaysInMonth()'>   
<div class='cal-top'>
    {{months[currDate.getMonth()]}}<br>
    {{currDate.getFullYear()}}
</div>
<table >
    <tr class='booker-head'>
        <th ng-repeat='day in days'>{{day}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='row in rows' ng-hide='rowIsNotEmpty()'>
        <td 
            ng-repeat='num in row track by $index' id='{{idNum[$parent.$index][$index]}}' 
            ng-click='checkIs(idNum[$parent.$index][$index])' ng-class='{active: isChanged[idNum[$parent.$index][$index]] && num}' 
            ng-hide='$parent.$index != 0 && !num'>{{num}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type='button' ng-click='lastMonth()' ng-show='isThisMonth()'><!--ShowIf-->Last Month</button>
<button type='button' ng-click='nextMonth()'>Next Month</button>


</body>
</html>

<pre>
    id: {{idNum}}
    isChanged: {{isChanged}}
    isAnyActive: {{isAnyActive}}
    rows: {{rows}}
    rowsArray: {{rowsArray}}
    lastChanged: {{lastChanged}}

</pre>
```

CSS:

```
table {
margin: 0 auto;
}

th {
background-color: rgb(51,102,154);
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

tr, td {
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100px;
height: 70px;
}

td:hover {
background-color: rgb(51, 102, 154);
color: white;
} 

.active {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

.cal-top {
background-color: rgb(51, 102, 154);
margin: 20px auto 0;
width: 701px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 4em;
color: white;
font-weight: 700;
border: solid 1px black;
border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: create fiddle it will be easy to fix

Comment: @gayathri https://jsfiddle.net/o6ovp6qy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi check the fiddle i added once condition inside the click so now only one date can select

```
for (x=0; x<$scope.isChanged.length; x++){
                      if(x == id)
                      {
                            $scope.isChanged[x] = true;
                                $scope.isChanged[x] = true;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                            $scope.isChanged[x] = false;
                                $scope.isChanged[x] = false;
                      }

        }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div class='cal-top'>
        {{months[currDate.getMonth()]}}<br>
        {{currDate.getFullYear()}}
    </div>
    <table >
        <tr class='booker-head'>
            <th ng-repeat='day in days'>{{day}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='row in rows' >
            <td 
                ng-repeat='num in row ' id='{{idNum[$parent.$index][$index]}}' 
                ng-click='checkIs(idNum[$parent.$index][$index])' ng-class='{active: isChanged[idNum[$parent.$index][$index]] && num}' 
                ng-hide='$parent.$index != 0 && !num'>{{num}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type='button' ng-click='lastMonth()' ng-show='isThisMonth()'><!--ShowIf-->Last Month</button>
    <button type='button' ng-click='nextMonth()'>Next Month</button>


<pre>
        id: {{idNum}}
        isChanged: {{isChanged}}
        isAnyActive: {{isAnyActive}}
        rows: {{rows}}
        rowsArray: {{rowsArray}}
        lastChanged: {{lastChanged}}
        </pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

and JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

        $scope.months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

        $scope.rows = [
            [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
            [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
            [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
            [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
            [29, 30, 31, '', '', '', ''],
            ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
            ];

        $scope.currDate = new Date();
        $scope.daysInMonth = 0;
        $scope.currDay = 0;
        $scope.monthStart = 0;
        $scope.monthEnd = 0;
        $scope.dayStart = 0;
        $scope.dif = 0;
        $scope.times = [];
        $scope.timeDate = new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        $scope.test;
        $scope.isChanged = [];
        $scope.lastChanged = '';
        $scope.isAnyActive = false;
        $scope.rowsArray = [''];

        $scope.idCount = 0;
        $scope.idNum = [[0,0],[0,0]];


        for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
            $scope.idNum[x] = [];
            for (y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++) {
                $scope.idNum[x][y] = $scope.idCount;
                $scope.isChanged[$scope.idCount] = false;
                $scope.idCount += 1;

            }
        }

        $scope.checkIs = function (id) {

                if ($scope.isChanged[id] == false && $scope.isAnyActive == false) {
                    $scope.isChanged[id] = true;
                    $scope.isAnyActive = true;
                }
                else if ($scope.isChanged[id] == true && $scope.isAnyActive == true){
                    $scope.isChanged[id] = false;
                    $scope.isAnyActive = false;
                }
                else if ($scope.isChanged[id] == false && $scope.isAnyActive == true) {
                    $scope.isChanged[id] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                  $scope.isChanged = false;
                }
                    for (x=0; x<$scope.isChanged.length; x++){
                      if(x == id)
                      {
                            $scope.isChanged[x] = true;
                                $scope.isChanged[x] = true;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                            $scope.isChanged[x] = false;
                                $scope.isChanged[x] = false;
                      }

        }


        }

        $scope.calLayout = function(){

            for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
                for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                    if ($scope.rows[x][y] == 1) {
                        $scope.dif = y - $scope.monthStart.getDay();

                    }
                }
            }



            for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
                for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                    $scope.rows[x][y] += $scope.dif;
                }
            }


            for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
                for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                    if ($scope.rows[x][y] <= 0){
                        $scope.rows[x][y] = '';
                    }
                }
            }

            for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
                for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                        if (($scope.rows[x][y] - $scope.dif) == $scope.daysInMonth){
                            for (i = -($scope.dif); i > 0; i--){
                                if (y+i > 6) {
                                    $scope.rows[x+1][y-7+i] = ($scope.rows[x][y]+i);
                                }
                                else {
                                    $scope.rows[x][y+i] = ($scope.rows[x][y]+i);
                                }
                            }
                        }


                }
            }
            $scope.idCount2 = 0;
            for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++){
                for(y=0; y<$scope.rows[x].length; y++){
                    $scope.rowsArray[$scope.idCount2] = $scope.rows[x][y];
                    $scope.idCount2 += 1;
                }
            }
        }


        $scope.getDaysInMonth = function () {
            monthStart = new Date($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth(), 1);
            monthEnd = new Date ($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth()+1, 1);
            $scope.monthStart = monthStart;
            $scope.monthEnd = monthEnd;
            $scope.daysInMonth = (monthEnd - monthStart)/(1000*60*60*24);
            $scope.calLayout();
        }

        $scope.getMonthStartDay = function (){
            $scope.currDay = $scope.currDate.getDate();
            return $scope.monthStart.getDay();
        }

        $scope.setActive = function(num) {
            $scope.activated = num;
        }

        $scope.isActive = function(num) {
            /*Insert if statement to disallow empty cells from being selected*/; 
            return $scope.activated === num;
        }

        $scope.nextMonth = function (){
            $scope.resetRows();
            $scope.currDate = new Date ($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth()+1, $scope.currDate.getDate());
            $scope.getDaysInMonth();
            $scope.getTimeList();
        }

        $scope.lastMonth = function (){
            $scope.resetRows();
            $scope.currDate = new Date ($scope.currDate.getFullYear(), $scope.currDate.getMonth()-1, $scope.currDate.getDate());
            $scope.getDaysInMonth();
        }

        $scope.isThisMonth = function (){
            var now = new Date;
            if ($scope.currDate.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && $scope.currDate.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear()){
                return false;
            } 
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }



        $scope.rowIsNotEmpty = function () {

            for (x=0; x<$scope.rows.length; x++) {

                var rowCount = 0;

                for (y=0; y<$scope.rows.length; y++) {
                    if ($scope.rows[x][y] == '') {
                        rowCount += 1;
                    }
                }

                if (rowCount == rows[x].length){
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

        $scope.resetRows = function (){

            $scope.rows = [
                [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
                [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
                [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
                [29, 30, 31, '', '', '', ''],
                ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
                ];

        }
});
```

and css

/* Put your css in here */

```
table {
margin: 0 auto;
}

th {
background-color: rgb(51,102,154);
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

tr, td {
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100px;
height: 70px;
}

td:hover {
background-color: rgb(51, 102, 154);
color: white;
} 

.active {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

.cal-top {
background-color: rgb(51, 102, 154);
margin: 20px auto 0;
width: 701px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 4em;
color: white;
font-weight: 700;
border: solid 1px black;
border-bottom: none;
}
```

for reference https://plnkr.co/edit/zGuDSuqdRiYsWB2ZKlgO?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind explaining why my logic didn't work in this case?

Comment: Hi i added only for (x=0; x<$scope.isChanged.length; x++){
       if(x == id)
       {
          $scope.isChanged[x] = true;
           $scope.isChanged[x] = true;
       }
       else
       {
          $scope.isChanged[x] = false;
           $scope.isChanged[x] = false;
       }      and i changed the angular library is missing and the logic which i added if the onclick id matches inside the array then i add the class remaining i removed

Comment: Happy coding @MoSheikh